# Having charset "utf8mb4" - does it mean every character takes 4 bytes, or only those that need 4 bytes?

Tags: mysql, mariadb, mysql-8.0, utf-8, mariadb-10.5

I have a `VARCHAR(80) utf8mb4` column, and I'm testing adding some ASCII & Emoji characters, and use `LENGTH()` and `CHAR_LENGTH()` to understand the differences.

From reading in different places, my understanding is that each character on a `utf8mb4` column would take 4 bytes. However, it appears that it may not be the case, if I understand `LENGTH()` as giving me the actual size that the specific contents are taking on that field.

Is it correct that a row with "aaaa" contents would take less storage than a row with ""?

[image]

Answer (score 7):

Actually, my answer is in the Documentation:
https://mariadb.com/kb/en/unicode/

> UTF-8 encoding using one to three bytes per character. Basic Latin
> letters, numbers and punctuation use one byte. European and Middle
> East letters mostly fit into 2 bytes. Korean, Chinese, and Japanese
> ideographs use 3-bytes. No supplementary characters are stored.
>
> utf8mb4   -- Same as utf8, but stores supplementary characters in four
> bytes.

Also, as per https://mariadb.com/kb/en/data-type-storage-requirements/

> **String Data Types**
> In the descriptions below, M is the declared column length (in characters or in bytes), while len is the actual length in bytes of the value.
> VARCHAR(M) -- len + 1 bytes if column is 0 – 255 bytes, len + 2 bytes if column may require more than 255 bytes

So, for `VARCHAR(80) utf8mb4`,
80x4 > 255, so a field with "aaaa" will take 6 bytes (len + 2)

Answer (score 0):

When mysql/mariadb creates columns for UTF8 data they are created big enough to fit any string having given encoding.

`VARCHAR(80) COLLATE 'utf8_general_ci'` column will be exactly 80x3=240 bytes long.
`VARCHAR(80) COLLATE 'utf8mb4_general_ci'` column will be exactly 80x4=320 bytes long.

P.S.
InnoDB engine has so called "overflow pages" for table storage where all long data resides. The root page stores only a prefix for indexing and a pointer to the following page. The same is for `TEXT` and `BLOB` types.

That is why "row size" for table returned by `SHOW TABLE STATUS` can be less than max data size table is able to store.

Comment: Thank you very much for this. But is this saying, then, that a VARCHAR(80) is by default taking 240 bytes of storage per row? I thought VARCHAR's purpose was to be variable sized, as otherwise we would use CHAR(80).

Comment: @Nuno, no, the difference between `CHAR` and `VARCHAR` is that `CHAR` always pads to the given length with spaces, while `VARCHAR` stores the length of the data that has been stored. So `VARCHAR(80)` needs (at least) 81 bytes. The record format in the table is fixed to make access locations predictable during scans.

Comment: I don't think this answer is correct. Please see my updated answer above. A developer of MariaDB pointed me to that link and confirmed that VARCHAR doesn't reserve all the space.